# SVN Repository - position of original project files

Tags: svn, fsfs

I have a Debian 6 server with Apache and a folder containing all the files of a project we're working on. The project is stored in /var/project 
The site of the project are accessible (through Apache) from browser through http://project.local
I installed SVN on the server in order to make control version on the project.

I created the repository (FSFS) on /var/projectrepo with

svnadmin create /var/projectrepo

I installed TortoiseSVN on Windows clients and did a checkout of the project on them.

Now: the files of the project in the original position ( /var/project) can even be deleted because now the repository keeps all the files and changes. But where? Inside  /var/projectrepo there are no folders containing the project files. I mean: I know that SVN keeps the deltas, but a delta needs an original complete file ad a starting point. Where is this "starting point" stored?

If I want to keep visiting the project from browser I know I have to make a post-commit script so that the files in the original position are kept up to date (latest release).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inside /var/projectrepo there are no folders containing the project files.

Subversion stores repositories as databases, not as filesystem-mirror. All deltas (and "nothing" -> "some data" **is also** delta) stored in *some files and directories* inside `/var/projectrepo`, even if directory-tree inside `projectrepo` have different structure. But any SVN-client can communicate with repository and present (if needed: `svn ls`, `svn co`) project tree inside repository node in original form